# Word meaning in "Radio frequency site survey"

Tags: meaning, technical

I have noticed that "Radio frequency site survey" is translated to my native language with omision of "site" word. The same goes for "wireless site survey" or just "RF site", "site survey". What is the meaning of "site" in this context? Is it "place"?

Comment: Quite likely, but the author should be able to tell you more precisely.

Comment: While I suppose a "site survey" **might** be tautologous since all surveys must take place somewhere, it does usually indicate an examination **of the site itself,** rather than simply **at** the site. Thus an "RF site survey" would be a survey of the site with respect to RF emissions. Quite why your language should translate it out of existence is out of scope here (and you didn't ask that), although it is intriguing.

Comment: Unless the context is unambiguous and the audience is knowledgeable about it, "site" is **required**. It's after all, a site survey, not a survey of frequencies, or a survey that uses RF. Also @AndrewLeach **Wireless site survey** (WP) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_site_survey "The survey usually involves a site visit to test for RF interference, ..."